# PHPExcel Multi Sheet Loop Issue

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I'm developing a small class that will allow you to pass queries and it will create a worksheet for each query.

**FYI: This class is still in development and I will be reducing down into smaller functions.**

My issue is that for some reason my sheet increment is off and I cant figure out where to put it.

I am calling my class like this:

```
$ex2 = new ExportToExcel2('Somefile');
$ex2->AddSheet('Sheet1', 'Select * from Division;');
$ex2->AddSheet('Sheet2', 'Select * from Zone');
$ex2->ExportMultiSheet();
```

I should have two tabs, "Sheet1" and "Sheet2". This is how my sheet ends up looking. All the data is on Sheet1 and Worksheet.

[image]

Here is my class:

```
class ExportToExcel2 {

    public $AllSheetData = [];
    protected $SheetData = [];
    protected $PHPExcel = '';
    protected $FileName = '';

    function __construct($_filename) {
        $this->FileName = $_filename;
        $this->PHPExcel = new PHPExcel;
    }

    public function AddSheet($_WorkSheetName, $_Query) {
        $this->SheetData['Sheet_Name'] = $_WorkSheetName;
        $this->SheetData['Query'] = $_Query;
        $this->AllSheetData[] = $this->SheetData;
        unset($this->SheetData);
    }

    public function ExportMultiSheet() {

        $Result='';
        $count=0;
        $this->PHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        foreach($this->AllSheetData as $subarray)
        {

            foreach($subarray as $key => $value)
            {

                if($count>0)
                {
                    $this->PHPExcel->createSheet($count);
                    $this->PHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($count);
                }

                if($key == 'Query') {

                    $Result = dbQuery($value);

                    //set header row
                    $row = 1; // 1-based index
                    $row_data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($Result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
                    $col = 0;
                    foreach(array_keys($row_data) as $key) {
                        $this->PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $key);
                        $col++;
                    }

                    //set body rows
                    $row2 = 2;
                    while($row_data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($Result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        $col2 = 0;

                        foreach($row_data as $key=>$value) {
                            $this->PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col2, $row2, $value);
                            $col2++;
                        }
                        $row2++;
                    }

                    $count++; 
                }
                if($key =='Sheet_Name')  {
                    $this->PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($value);
                }


                //set all columns to align left
                $this->PHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT);

                //show gridlines?
                $this->PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setShowGridlines(true);

                //set columns a through z to auto width
                for($col = 'A'; $col !== 'Z'; $col++) {
                    $this->PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                        ->getColumnDimension($col)
                        ->setAutoSize(true);
                }
            }

        }


        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xls"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->PHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');

        exit;
    }
}
```

Any ideas on where to place my $count++?

### Solved, Here is the finished class(until its not finished again)

```
class ExportToExcel2 {

    public $AllSheetData = [];
    protected $SheetData = [];
    protected $PHPExcel  = '';
    protected $FileName  = '';

    function __construct($_filename) {

        $this->FileName = $_filename;
        $this->PHPExcel = new PHPExcel;

        //clean the output buffer before download
        ob_clean();
    }


    public function AddSheet($_WorkSheetName, $_Query) {
        $this->SheetData['Sheet_Name'] = $_WorkSheetName;
        $this->SheetData['Query'] = $_Query;
        $this->AllSheetData[] = $this->SheetData;
        unset($this->SheetData);
    }


    public function ExportMultiSheet($_ExportType='xls') {
        if(!empty($this->AllSheetData)) {
            $count=0;$Result='';
            $this->PHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
            foreach($this->AllSheetData as $subarray) {

                if($count>0){
                    $this->PHPExcel->createSheet(null);
                    $this->PHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($count);
                }
                $count++; 
                foreach($subarray as $key => $value) {

                    if($key == 'Query') {
                        $Result = dbQuery($value);
                        $this->SetHeaderCells($Result);
                        $this->SetbodyCells($Result);

                    }
                    if($key =='Sheet_Name')  {
                        $this->PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($value);
                    }

                }
            }

            $this->ExportType($_ExportType);
        }
    }


    public function ExportSingleSheet($_Query, $_ExportType='xls') {
        $Result = dbQuery($_Query);
        $this->SetHeaderCells($Result);
        $this->SetBodyCells($Result);
        $this->SetProperties();
        $this->ExportType($_ExportType);
    }


    private function ExportType($_ExportType) {
        if($_ExportType=='xls') {
            $this->DownloadXLS();
        } 
        else if($_ExportType=='csv') {
            $this->DownloadCSV();
        }
    }


    private function SetProperties() {

        //set all columns to align left
        $this->PHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT);

        //show gridlines?
        $this->PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setShowGridlines(true);

        //set columns a through z to auto width
        for($col = 'A'; $col !== 'Z'; $col++) {
            $this->PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                ->getColumnDimension($col)
                ->setAutoSize(true);
        }

        //set the first sheet to open first
        $this->PHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    }


    private function DownloadXLS() {
        $this->SetProperties();
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$this->FileName.'-'.date("y.m.d").'.xls"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->PHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');

        exit;
    }


    private function DownloadCSV() {
        $this->SetProperties();
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$this->FileName.'-'.date("y.m.d").'.csv"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_CSV($this->PHPExcel);
        $objWriter->save("php://output");

        exit;
    }


    private function SetHeaderCells($Result) {
        $row = 1; // 1-based index
        $row_data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($Result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
        $col = 0;
        foreach(array_keys($row_data) as $key) {
            $this->PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $key);
            $col++;
        }
    }


    private function SetBodyCells($Result) {
        $row2 = 4;
        while($row_data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($Result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $col2 = 0;

            foreach($row_data as $key=>$value) {
                $this->PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col2, $row2, $value);
                $col2++;
            }
            $row2++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first move the sheet generation code from the `foreach($subarray` loop to your `foreach($this->AllSheetData` (since you want to add new sheet for every.. well.. new sheet. Not for every new sheet property).

You should then use a very similar code to the one you had, and `$counter` will be used only within that part of the code. Note that to create a new sheet and place is as the last one, you should simply pass `null` to the `createSheet()` method.

So your code should look like this:

```
public function ExportMultiSheet() {

    ...
    $count = 0;
    foreach($this->AllSheetData as $subarray)
    {
      if ($count > 0)
      {
          $this->PHPExcel->createSheet(null);
          $this->PHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($count);
      }
      $count++

      foreach($subarray as $key => $value)
      ...
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks man, this got me very close. the issue is that now I am overwriting the first sheet data with the second sheet data and the "Sheet2" is empty. I changed it exactly like you suggested.

Comment: Did you make sure to remove any other reference to `$count`? Here's the code I've used based on your question: http://pastebin.com/EGwKyMGY It'll simply write the `$count` to `A1` cell on each new sheet. See that it's working for you, and then try to figure out the differences from your code.

Comment: I had a SetProperties function firing and in there I was setting the activeindex. Working now. i added my finished class above.